# Protobuf net not told to Serialize a System.Object but still get error: No serializer defined for type: System.Object

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

---

System.InvalidOperationException: {"It was not possible to prepare a serializer for: SomeObject 
Inner exception: {"No serializer defined for type: System.Object"}

Could I be getting errors from something else in my code?  I have a ton of classes I'm attempting to serialize but I am testing the simpler ones first to make sure my program works generally.

---

**ALSO VERY IMPORTANT: SomeObject is inherited by other classes (I am just serializing this base class when I get the error though)**

---

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(AnotherObject))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(YetAgainObject))]
public class SomeObject {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    String mName = "";
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    String mOwner = "";
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    String mDesc = "";
}

[ProtoContract]
public class AnotherObject : SomeObject{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public object[] someList{ get; set: }
}
```

....

Comment: You said your `VObjectType` is correctly setup. Have you tried to serialize it alone?

Comment: Yes it serializes but throws the error. I figured it out. I will edit the question and post my answer so it makes sense.

Comment: @Arthur Rey I finished my edit, it is much better phrased and I answered it below. There just isn't a "stack trace" for Protobuf net inheritance hierarchies so it throws the error on the class currently being serialized even if its a parent.

Answer (score 3):

In the process of serializing the original object it checks if ALL of the      **ProtoInclude** statements. Also it checks for correct serialization structures and qualities! If there is an error in ANY of those it will throw an error in the one you are trying to serialize, but it won't tell you which one it is from rather say that the class you inherited from caused the error.

## So ***caution*** is needed when doing large amounts of classes without individually checking them. This is true for other errors other than an object not being defined for serialization.

Thus my error was in AnotherObject and the fix for that is specifically:

```
 [ProtoContract]
 public class AnotherObject : SomeObject{
     [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
     public object[] someList{ get; set: }
 }
```

Because you have to tell it that object contains something that is serializable (and it will trust you).